# Why does slicing this string and making it an array add undefined to the elements of the array?

Tags: javascript

This is my code - I want to store a slice of the string 'areas' into an array.
Unfortunately, I am getting undefined attached to the array elements. I am new to javascript and coding as a whole.

Any help would be amazing :-)

```
let areas = '10101101110001101010011101001110000101011000101010100010011001101100110110011010000101001110101';

// checking guards
leftGuard = areas.substr(0,3);
if (leftGuard !== '101')
    {
        return result.message1;
    }

centerGuard = areas.substr(45,5);
if (centerGuard !== '01010')
    {
        return result.message2;
    }

rightGuard = areas.substr(92,3);
if (rightGuard !== '101')
    {
        return result.message3;
    }

// segregate the areas string into left and right digit and store in an array
let newAreaLeft = areas.slice(3,45);
let newAreaRight = areas.slice(51,92);

// left nos.
let i = 0, j = 0;

while (j < 42)
    {
        realLeft[i] += newAreaLeft.substr(j,7);
        j += 7;
        i++
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

undefined0110111,undefined0001101,undefined0100111,undefined0100111,undefined0000101,undefined0110001

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post the actual code.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. Just made the changes you said.

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized elements of an array are returned as `undefined`, which converts to "undefined" in a string expression.

Try setting `realLeft` with direct assignment instead of `+=` to overwrite undefined entries (if acceptable):

```
 realLeft[i] = newAreaLeft.substr(j,7);
```

Or set uninitialized values to the empty string before appending:

```
realLeft[i] = realLeft[i] || ""; // change falsey values to empty string
realLeft[i] += newAreaLeft.substr(j,7);
```